# PYTHON - Error while calling a outter function

Tags: python, function, arguments

This is the code where i created my function

```
#============= Importations =====================
from datetime import date

#============= Classe ===========================
class Pret :

    #----------- Constructeur -----------------------------

    def __init__(self,p_date:str,p_duree_max:int,p_nbr_renouv):
        #.... Déclaration des données membres ....
        self.__date_debut   = None # date
        self.__duree_max    = 0 # int
        self.__nbr_renouv   = 0 # int
        #.... Code ....
        self.__date_debut   = p_date
        self.__duree_max    = p_duree_max
        self.__nbr_renouv   = p_nbr_renouv

    #----------- Autres méthodes  -------------------------
    def calculer_date_retour():
        debut=self.__date_debut
        debut_a_auj= debut.toordinal()
        date_retour=fromordinal(debut_a_auj+self.__duree_max)
        return date_retour
```

The "calculer_date_retour" function should give me a date from "date_debut" and "duree_max" who's are given from this program :

```
#----------- Importations et fonctions ----------------
from datetime import date
from pret import Pret
#----------- Déclaration des variables ----------------
debut = None
dates = None
duree = 0
nbr_renouv = 0
compte_a = None
x=0
#----------- Code -----------
debut=date(2000,1,10)
print(debut)
dates = date.today()
duree = 10
nbr_renouv = 2


compte_a=Pret(dates, duree, nbr_renouv)
print(compte_a.calculer_date_retour())
```

but when i try the `print(compte_a.calculer_date_retour)` it give me error like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:Fichier de test.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(compte_a.calculer_date_retour())
TypeError: calculer_date_retour() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

basicly it say that i give an argument to it but i cant figure out where am i giving him one

Comment: Looks like you need the reference to the `compte_a` instance. Have you tried defining your function as `def calculer_date_retour(self):`?

Comment: @BorrajaX just tried and it give me a new error...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/Fichier de test.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(compte_a.calculer_date_retour())
  File "Z:/pret.py", line 45, in calculer_date_retour
    date_retour=fromordinal(debut_a_auj+self.__duree_max)
NameError: global name 'fromordinal' is not defined

Comment: That's because in your `calculer_date_retour()` you are calling a `fromordinal` function that is not defined in your code (this includes imports) I guess you wanna do something like `date.fromordinal(debut_a_auj+self.__duree_max)`...

Comment: @Olivier Turcotte the error is basically saying you don't have a function called `fromordinal()`, so either remove it or make the function

Comment: @Olivier Turcotte  I've updated my answer based on your error

Comment: @BorrajaX it work now, Thanks alot i was struggling on it for like about an hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling a function from a `class`, `self` is always given as a default argument, this means you need `self` as a parameter when definining the function

```
def calculer_date_retour(self):
    debut=self.__date_debut
    debut_a_auj= debut.toordinal()
    date_retour=date.fromordinal(debut_a_auj+self.__duree_max)
    return date_retour
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put self in the declaration of the class method.

`def calculer_date_retour(self):`

The `.` operator in python introduces the object as the first argument of the method you are calling.

`a.b()` makes: `b(a)` and that's how you access to properties using `self`.

You are sending one argument without noticing.

Comment: BTW: `self` name is a convention, you can call it whatever you want

Comment: It's a pretty strong convention, though. :-)

You could just as well name all your non-private class attributes starting with an underline, but every python programmer will think that they are private.

Comment: Yes, it is. I wanted make clear that `self` is not a reserved word or something. :)
In python conventions are very strong in general.